# vb.net maximize program from notification area

Tags: vb.net, forms, notifyicon

I have a program which contains few project and get reference to them. When I start program the Main Form is open. Now, I can click button and start form one of my project. I set Main Form to minimize to Notify Icon. Now when I finish with Form (from project) I want to maximize Main Form from Notify Icon.

How can I do this?

This is how I start Form and minimize Main Form to Notify Icon:

```
Dim instance As New Machines.FormMain
    instance.Show()

    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "TF Tools"
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Machines Readings"
    NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5)

    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    ShowInTaskbar = False
```

I have Solution with 3 projects. Main project is TF Tools when I stat TF_Tools.Form1 start. I click button which start project Machines.Form1. TF_Tools.Form1 is minimized to Notify Icon. I want TF_Tools.Form1 maximized when Machines.Form1 is closing. I was try to do this like that:

```
ShowInTaskbar = True
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
```

This is work when I double click on icon in Notify Icon. But when I put this in Machines.Form1 closing event it’s not work. I was try to change Me. WindowState for TF_Tools.Form1.WindowState but it’s not work. I was think to add TF_Tools as a reference to Machines but I can’t do this.

Comment: Not sure if i have understood the question right.... Can you not use the `.Closing` event of the second form? - You might want to add a bit more code as most will understand the code even if they don't quite follow your explanation.